# LayoutInflator throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, layout-inflater

I'm new to android. And I'm trying to manipulate the TextView from aother class out of the GUI class which is the MainActivity class. But it throws an exception.

Following is the code i used...

```
Context ctx;
private SharedPreferences pref;

LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
TextView tv_datePick = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.pickDate);
tv_datePick.setText(pref.getString(Constants.SELECTED_DATE,""));
```

I'm getting a date stored in `SharedPreference` and setting it to the `TextView`

Following is the Exception i get..

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: srt.com.srtnew_nisal, PID: 25351
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.from(LayoutInflater.java:219)
  at srt.com.srtnew_nisal.DatePickerFragment.onDateSet(DatePickerFragment.java:61)
  at android.app.DatePickerDialog.onClick(DatePickerDialog.java:134)
  at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:162)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5290)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:911)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:706)
```

Following is the full code of the class that I'm using the LayoutInflator

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    Context ctx;
    private SharedPreferences pref;


    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        pref = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("Users",0);
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {

        String new_month = "";

        if(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(month))<10) {
            new_month="0"+String.valueOf(month);
        }else{
            new_month = String.valueOf(month);
        }
        Log.d("month new",year+"-"+new_month+"-"+dayOfMonth);

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putString(Constants.SELECTED_DATE,year+"-"+new_month+"-"+dayOfMonth);
        editor.apply();

        Log.d("shared pref",pref.getString(Constants.SELECTED_DATE,""));

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
        TextView tv_datePick = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.pickDate);
        tv_datePick.setText(pref.getString(Constants.SELECTED_DATE,""));


    }
}
```

What have i done wrong here? Am I doing the right way?

Comment: where are you initializing your contex `ctx` ?

Comment: I have not initialized the ctx variable. I have declared it at the top.

Comment: Change  `LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);` to `LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);`

Comment: @KeLiuyue it doesn't work here. It says `cannot be convert to Context`

Comment: You need a constructor and pass `context` from `MainActivity` to it

Comment: Could you show detail code  ?@NisalMalindaLivera

Comment: use `LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());` .And try it.

Comment: Also you can try `LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater(); ` in your code @NisalMalindaLivera

Comment: @KeLiuyue Both of them worked without any runtime erors. But i cant get the `TextView` updated. You have any idea about that issue?

Comment: And you need to add `SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getActivity().getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(SP_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);` in your code .And make sure that `pref.getString(Constants.SELECTED_DATE,"")` was not null .@NisalMalindaLivera

Comment: ctx is obviously null.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

Here are several other ways you can get a reference to the LayoutInflater object:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

LayoutInflater inflater = ctx.getLayoutInflater();

LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

Also, make sure that your Context ctx variable is not null. For this you should pass the Context from the constructor of the class.

Comment: `LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);` i tried this and it also threw the same exception

Comment: It seems that the problem is that your Context ctx is null. You should provide it a valid Context reference. Try passing the context from the constructor.